# How to make background image blur and not the content?

Tags: php, html

I've tried to implement the blur attribute to the image but it just blurs the body. I'm not sure how to make display it right. Thanks!
Here is the website.

http://79.170.44.80/sicuandomain.com/

Here is the html, and style, php code

```
<?php
  $bg = array('Abstract.jpg', 'Antelope.jpg', 'Bahamas.jpg', 'Beach.jpg' ); // array of filenames

  $i = rand(0, count($bg)-1); 
  $selectedBg = "$bg[$i]"; // set variable equal to which random filename was chosen
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Contact Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

    <style type="text/css">
body{
    content:"";
    background: url(images/<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: -999;
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <form id="form" action="welcome.php" class="form-horizontal" method="POST">
                    <h1 class="">My Contact Form</h1>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="fname" class="form-control" pattern="[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*"required/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="lname" class="form-control" required/>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="email" class="form-control" required/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Mobile" name="mobile" class="form-control" required/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <select name="gender" class="form-control" required>
                                <option value="">Select one</option>
                                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                                <option value="Female">Female</option>
                                <option value="Others">I'm not sure</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form group">
                        <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-6">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add
                            </button>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js.css" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

demo fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jLGFp/3/

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top: 0;
}
p {
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top: 0;
}
```